# How to filter Kotest tests using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, kotest

I would like to execute only a specific subset of tests locally to exclude slowly running integration tests. So only tests with the `*Test` suffix should be included, those ending with `*IT` should be excluded.

The official Kotest guide offers command line parameters, through the feature called [conditional evaluation](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/conditional/conditional-tests-with-gradle.html), but the guide mentions only Gradle. How can I use conditional evaluation with Maven or IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that you have to add a VM option in the run configuration... First, I had to click on `Modify options` and then `Add VM options` (`Alt+V` hotkey).

[image: add VM options]

In the VM options, I had to add `-Dkotest.filter.specs=*Test` (without single or double quotes). If I added single quotes (as in the reference documentation) it did not work, although I'm using Windows 10.
[image: add test filter]

The documentation is a bit misleading. The VM argument `-Dkotest.filter.tests` is filtering based on the `name` parameter of the `should()` member function in  [`ShouldSpec`](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/testing-styles.html#should-spec).

So a configuration `-Dkotest.filter.tests=*dummy*` will execute the following test case inside `should() {...}`:

```kotlin
class DoesNothingTest: ShouldSpec({
    should("do some dummy things") {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this require having [Kotest IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14080-kotest) installed?

Comment: @aSemy - yes, it does.